# Return pivot data to view in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm not quite sure what it is I'm doing wrong...

I've got a recipe project that I'm learning with, but I can't seem to get the data joined by a pivot table into the view.

The user creates a recipe [at  (name, description, portions, tags etc), and is then directed to the "create ingredients" view. From here they are adding ingredients via an Ajax request, which is successfully saving to the **ingredients** table, and the link in **recipe_ingredients**.

I'm dynamically adding the ingredients to the table via ajax, but when the user refreshes the page, I need it to loop through the ingredients table, and return just those associated with the given recipe.

I'm using the following loop, but it isn't working:

```
@foreach($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
  {{$recipe->ingredient->name}}
@endforeach
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR):
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ingredients.recipe_ingredients' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `ingredients` where `ingredients`.`recipe_ingredients` is null and `ingredients`.`recipe_ingredients` is not null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\recipes\resources\views\ingredients\create.blade.php)
```

---

**INFO:**

I've got 3 tables:
**recipes**, **ingredients**, **recipe_ingredients**

**Recipe Model:**

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
  public function ingredients(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ingredient', 'recipe_ingredients', 'recipe_id', 'ingredient_id');
  }
```

**Ingredients Model:**

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public function recipes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe', 'recipe_ingredients', 'ingredient_id', 'recipe_id');
}
```

**Ingredients Controller**

```
public function create($recipe_id)
{
  $recipe = Recipe::find($recipe_id);
  return view('ingredients.create')->withRecipe($recipe);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255'
  ]);

  $ingredient = new Ingredient;
  $ingredient->name = $request->name;
  $ingredient->save();

  $recipe = Recipe::find($request->id);
  $ingredient->recipes()->attach($recipe->id);

  $data = [
    'success' => true,
    'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
    'name' => $ingredient->name,
    'recipe' => $recipe,
  ] ;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**Ajax Script for saving ingredients to db:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#ingredientName").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
      type: "post",
      data: "name="+name,
      dataType:'json',
      url: "{{ route('ingredients.store', ['id' => $recipe->id]) }}",
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success my-0">'+data.name+' added</div>');
        $("#msg").toggleClass("invisible")
        $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);
        $("#ingredientsTable").append('<tr><td scope="col" class="align-middle">'+data.name+'</td></tr>');
      }
    });
  })
})
</script>
```

**Relevant part of the view:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <!-- 
        <p><b>Est. prep time:</b></p>
        <p><b>Est. cooking time:</b></p>
        -->
        <p><b>Portions:</b> {{ $recipe->portions }}</p>
        <p><b>Creator:</b> <a href="#">{{ $recipe->user->name }}</a></p>
        @if($recipe->created_at == $recipe->updated_at) 
          <p><b>Created:</b> {{ $recipe->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
        @else
          <p><b>Updated:</b> {{ $recipe->updated_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
        @endif
        <!-- 
        <p><b>Rating:</b> <i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>&nbsp;(52)</p>
        -->

        <div id="tags">
          @foreach($recipe->tags as $tag)
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-{{$tag->colour}} btn-sm my-1">{{$tag->name}}</button>
          @endforeach
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <table class="table table-hover table-light" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Ingredients:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="ingredientsTable">

        @foreach($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
        {{$recipe->ingredient->name}}
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Routes:**

```
$ php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                      | Name               | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index                             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                 |                    | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                     | home               | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                    | login              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | login                    |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                   | logout             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email           | password.email     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset           | password.request   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}   | password.reset     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | recipes                  | recipes.store      | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@store                           | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | recipes                  | recipes.index      | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@index                           | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/create           | recipes.create     | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@create                          | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{id}/ingredients | ingredients.create | App\Http\Controllers\IngredientsController@create                      | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | recipes/{id}/ingredients | ingredients.store  | App\Http\Controllers\IngredientsController@store                       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{recipe}         | recipes.show       | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@show                            | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE    | recipes/{recipe}         | recipes.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@destroy                         | web,auth     |
|        | PUT|PATCH | recipes/{recipe}         | recipes.update     | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@update                          | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{recipe}/edit    | recipes.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@edit                            | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | register                 |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                 | register           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | steps                    | steps.store        | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@store                             | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | steps                    | steps.index        | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@index                             | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | steps/create             | steps.create       | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@create                            | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | steps/{step}             | steps.show         | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@show                              | web,auth     |
```

**Migrations:**

**create_recipes_table**

```
Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->text('description');
  $table->integer('portions');
  $table->integer('user_id');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

**create_ingredients_table**

```
Schema::create('ingredients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('name');
    $table->boolean('approved')->nullable();
    $table->datetime('approved_at')->nullable();
    $table->integer('approved_by')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**create_recipe_ingredients_table**

```
Schema::create('recipe_ingredients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('recipe_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipes');

    $table->integer('ingredient_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredients');
});
```

Comment: table fields of recipes_ingredients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because your relationship on your Recipe model is not correct. Since the relationship between recipes and igredients is many-to-many, both models need to have [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship to the other model:

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    public function ingredients(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient', 'recipe_ingredients');
    }
}
```

There's also an error in your `foreach`, you should reference the `$ingredient` from the loop:

```
@foreach($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
  {{ $ingredient->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks! This has fixed one error, but now shows another. `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\recipes\resources\views\ingredients\create.blade.php)`

Comment: Ah yes, there's an error in your `foreach` as well. Check my update

Comment: I've just made the two changes suggested, and it's working. Thanks!! (Marked as correct).

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Just wanted to say, this is the third question of mine you've provided a correct answer too. Thanks for your ongoing help!